# Проблема нулевого елемента картнки при проверке

Tags: java, android, list

Создал приложение и картинку:

```
    courseImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("Image",0));
```

создал проверку на эдентичность элементов:

При елементарных проверках, такие как:

```
if(courseImage.getDrawable().getConstantState() == courseImage.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_java).getConstantState()){
//код
}
```

или же

```
if(getIntent().getIntExtra("courseImage", 0) == R.drawable.ic_java) {
//код
}
```

Я получаю вылет с такой ошибкой:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
 at com.example.adapters.CourseAdapter$1.onClick(CourseAdapter.java:63)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7751)
 at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7724)
 at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:858)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29332)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8280)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
```

Я знаю, что IndexOutOfBoundsException - ошибка связана с отсутсвием элемента в списке 63 строка это следуйший код:

```
                intent.putExtra("courseBg", Color.parseColor(courseList.get(position).getColor()));
```

Вот класс адаптера с этим элементом

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.CoursePage;
import com.example.R;
import com.example.model.Course;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

public class CourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseAdapter.CourseViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Course> courseList;

    public CourseAdapter(Context context, List<Course> courseList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.courseList = courseList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    //какой конкретно дизайн будем отображать для каждого элемента
    public CourseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View courseItems = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.course_item, parent, false);
        return new CourseAdapter.CourseViewHolder(courseItems);


    }
//Будем указивать что конкретно будем подставлять в дизайн
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull CourseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.courseBg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(courseList.get(position).getColor()));
    int imageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_"+courseList.get(position).getImg(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    holder.courseImage.setImageResource(imageId);

    holder.courseTitle.setText(courseList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.courseLevel.setText(courseList.get(position).getLevel());
    holder.coursePrice.setText(courseList.get(position).getPrice());


    //оброботчик нажатия на определённый элемент
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CoursePage.class);
                intent.putExtra("courseBg", Color.parseColor(courseList.get(position).getColor()));
                intent.putExtra("courseImage",imageId);
                intent.putExtra("courseTitle",courseList.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("coursePrice",courseList.get(position).getPrice());
                intent.putExtra("courseLevel",courseList.get(position).getLevel());
                intent.putExtra("courseId", courseList.get(position).getId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
//размер списка, будет выдаваться верный размер списка
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return courseList.size();
    }
//с какими элементами дизайна будем работать
    public static final class CourseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        LinearLayout courseBg;
        ImageView courseImage;
        TextView courseTitle, coursePrice, courseLevel;
        ListView listView;


        public CourseViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            courseBg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseBg);
            courseImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseImage);
            courseTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseTitle);
            coursePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            courseLevel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.level);
            listView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);



        }
    }


}
```

Можете объяснить как починить IndexOutOfBoundsException используя try-catch или как-то иначе? Благодарю

Comment: Я что-то не вижу этого условия в вашем адаптере и какое оно имеет отношение к проблеме непонятно. Проблема у вас в том, что на момент клика по элементу, список `courseList` оказывается пустым. То есть где-то вне адаптера он очищается и это есть не хорошо - если вы как-то переиспользуете список, передаваемый в адаптер, то следует передавать или создавать в адаптере его копию.

Comment: @woesss, я же по айди ищу элемент

Comment: Выведите строкой выше ошибки в лог размер courseList и значение position, сразу понятнее будет.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja,это отчёт ошибки с телефона (не эмулятора) стактрейса нету

Comment: Да в самой ошибке это написано: `Index: 0, Size: 0` - список пуст. Какой поиск по айди - вообще не понял о чём вы... Ошибка вылетает в обработчике клика на вызове `courseList.get(position)`

Comment: @woesss, я даже не понимаю причем тут список к обработке на нажатие, так как я получаю элементы с drawable., А не с массива

Comment: Где у вас строка 63? Что в этой строке написано? Где там drawable?

Comment: Все верно, проглядел, список пуст. Автор, у вас проблема со списком, не с drawable или imageview или поиском по id. `OnClickListener` когда срабатывает, список пуст, а вы все так же как и при байндинге из него что-то получить пытаетесь.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja,то есть вы рекомендуете удалить вытаскивание картинки с байдинга?

Comment: Нет, я рекомендую переписать `OnClickListener`, либо сделать как @woesss писал в самом первом сообщении.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja , а может это быть связано с очисткой списка при onDestroy, onStop? Без них у меня дублируются списки

Answer (score 1):

Судя по комментам вы меняете список с данными за пределами адаптера. И у вас в адаптер список передаётся по ссылке. Попробуйте использовать отдельный список в адаптере - так на него не будут влиять изменения снаружи:

```
public class CourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseAdapter.CourseViewHolder> {

    private List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CourseAdapter(List<Course> courseList) {
        this.courseList.clear();
        this.courseList.addAll(courseList);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: И обратите внимание - `context` вам передавать не нужно в адаптер - везде где он используется у вас есть доступ к View, из которого оный можно взять.

Comment: Увы, но нет, может можно как-то try-catch использовать?

Comment: Можно всё обложить `try-catch`-ами, но `CoursePage` у вас никогда не запустится, потому что код всегда будет попадать в `catch` и данные для интента негде взять, так как список, из которого вы их получаете - пустой. Нужно разбираться с причиной, а не бороться с последствиями.